# Return a key-value list, key is attribute and value is attribute's value from other Class

Tags: java, list, key-value

I have a Class `A` with `name` and `value` attributes.

```
public class A {
    private String name;
    private String value;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

I have another Class B, such as

```
public class B {
    private String attribute01;
    private String attribute01;
    private String attribute01;

    public String getAttribute01() {
        return attribute01;
    }
    public void setAttribute01(String name) {
        this.attribute01 = name;
    }
    ...
}
```

I would like to return a list with `A` type, having `attribute01` key and where value is `getAttribute01()` from `B`, such as `({attribute01, getAttribute01()},{attribute02, getAttribute02()})`.

How to implement it?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is your key-value list?

Comment: instead of list,you should use Map.your program is need to use list only?

Comment: You mean the key is the string ```"atribute01"```?

Comment: Thanks for reply, list is require since it is defined, the key-value list should like ((attribute01, getAttribute01()), (attribute02, getAttribute02()), (attribute03, getAttribute03()) ... )

Comment: Never put more information into comments; update your question instead.

Comment: Just to be precise: do you really want to use **a method "pointer"** as map value. Meaning: do you expect that one can turn to the list and say: ah, if I want attribute02, I can **call** the "value" that the list provides? Besides: you really want to study the concept of Maps/HashMaps in java.

Comment: @Jägermeister _"...list with type ```A```..."_, so I would assume both key and value would be ```String```.

Comment: @Jägermeister current data structure is defined like this, I know Maps/HashMasp is more efficient, I have to work on defined structure :(

Comment: It is not only about efficiency. It is also a matter of **design and code quality**. Often it seems cheaper to "work on defined structure"; but the problem is: when you build on bad ground, then everything you build on top of that ... is doomed to be "bad" as well. And what you showed so far looks pretty ... not so good.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I can use a very stupid way, such as

```
public List<A> keyvalueList(final B objB) {
List<A> list = new ArrayList<>();

A objA = new A();
objA.setName("attribute01");
objA.setValue(objB.getAttribute01());
list.add(objA);

objA = new A();
objA.setName("attribute02");
objA.setValue(objB.getAttribute02());
list.add(objA);

...

return list; 
}
```

Part of them hard coding, obvious it is not a smart way, any proposal.

Comment: Are you trying to answer your own question? If not; as said: **update** your question.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote sample code for List.Please check my code that is ok to use or not.I added another extra class C.in C,it has two attribute String nameFromA and String attFromB.You should add this C object to list.Following is sample code.

```
public class A {
    private String name;
    private String value;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
public class B {
    private String att1;
    private String att2;
    private String att3;
    public String getAtt1() {
        return att1;
    }
    public void setAtt1(String att1) {
        this.att1 = att1;
    }
    public String getAtt2() {
        return att2;
    }
    public void setAtt2(String att2) {
        this.att2 = att2;
    }
    public String getAtt3() {
        return att3;
    }
    public void setAtt3(String att3) {
        this.att3 = att3;
    }


}

public class C {
    private String namefromA;
    private String attfromB;
    public String getNamefromA() {
        return namefromA;
    }
    public void setNamefromA(String namefromA) {
        this.namefromA = namefromA;
    }
    public String getAttfromB() {
        return attfromB;
    }
    public void setAttfromB(String attfromB) {
        this.attfromB = attfromB;
    }
}

    public class Test {

        public static void main(String args[]){
            C c = new C();
            A a = new A();
            B b = new B();
            a.setName("A1");
            b.setAtt1("100");
            c.setNamefromA(a.getName());
            c.setAttfromB(b.getAtt1()); 
List list = new ArrayList();
//use generic 
list.add(c);

        }

    }
```

if you don't want to use class C,then you can use Test class like that

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    private String nameFromA;
    private String valueFromB;


    public Test(String nameFromA, String valueFromB) {
        super();
        this.nameFromA = nameFromA;
        this.valueFromB = valueFromB;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){

        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();
        a.setName("A1");
        b.setAtt1("100");
        Test test = new Test(a.getName(),b.getAtt1());
        List list = new ArrayList();
        list.add(test);

    }


}
```

This is my opinion only.Please check it is ok or not.